# Best way to vertically-align children in an inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I’m trying to vertically align the content in the cyan div without using one of the following methods:

- Vertical align (as it requires displaying as a table & will have knock-on effects on the parent div padding etc)
- Line height (as there’s more than 1 line with 3 actual spans)
- Table (due to knock-on effects like with vertical align)
- Absolute positioning (as some other cyan divs will have more text than others, meaning some will have more lines than others)
- Equal top & bottom padding (same reason as abs positioning)
- Flexboxes (I forbid these as they have serious knock-on effects!)

The cyan div is an inline-block. What would be the best way to achieve this? I want to be able to set the padding between each of the 3 spans to space them out nicely.

NOTE:
I've updated my answer to include flex positioning but on mobile view the 2nd cyan div below is not aligned centrally

```css
.sections {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 62px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.foster-cta {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: cyan;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 30px;

/* adding display flex makes the 2nd cyan div below not aligned centrally on mobile view */
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items: center;
display: inline-flex;

}
.foster-top {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.foster-middle {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.foster-bottom {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="sections">
        <h1>header 1 tag</h1>
        <p>some random text to go here lorem ipsum sit semei geono wfnwoenfowe fwenfuowe ffe efnpi enfo wfeonwofun weofun weofnwe ofunwe foiej.</p>
        <div class="foster-cta">
            <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
            <span class="foster-middle">some random text here</span>
            <span class="foster-bottom">a load more random text goes here that will be more descriptive and longer.</span>
        </div><!--
        --><div class="foster-cta" style="margin-left:50px;">
            <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
            <span class="foster-middle">text</span>
            <span class="foster-bottom"> a load more random text goes here that will be more descriptive and longer a load more random text goes here that will be more descriptive and longer.</span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Still flexbox is your best bet:  .foster-cta { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center; }

Comment: I see your point but this causes knock-on effects. doing what you suggest does vertically-align the content in the cyan div but it then displaces the other cyan div next to it

Comment: You need to show what the knock-on effects are in each case in order for us to demonstrate how they can be avoided.

Comment: fair comment. I've updated my answer in this thread with flex positioning and it mostly works, however on mobile view the 2nd cyan div at the bottom is not aligned centrally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox is your best bet when doing any sort of aligning in CSS. The code is also very simple:

```
.div-parent {

   display: flex;

}

.div-child {

   align-self: center;

}
```

This will align vertically centered only